# Macro building coordinates breaks \addplot command in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, macros

I would like to create a plot of a few data points that are defined at the top of the document using something like:
`\newcommand{\test}{{3,4,2,5}}`

To do this, I created a macro that parses these values and turns them into something like:

`(0,3) (1,4) (2,2) (3,5)`

Unfortunately, if I use a macro to generate this, I get a
`Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 33.`
where line 33 is what asks pgfplot to add the coordinates to the graph (see the full file below).

On the other hand, if I directly create the coordinates:

```
\newcommand{\tester}{ { (1.0,3)  (2.0,4)  (3.0,2)  (4.0,5) } }
...
\addplot coordinates { {\tester} };
```

Things work well. If on the other hand, I use the macro:

```
\newcommand{\tester}{ \makeCoords{\test} }
...
\addplot coordinates { {\tester} };
```

then I get that compile error. Note that I can print out `\tester` when creating the coordinates, and everything looks good to me.

Sample test code is below. By switching out comments on line 18 and 19, you can go back and forth between seeing things work and breaking things. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}{{3,4,2,5}}

\newcommand{\pgfval}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult}

\newcommand{\makeCoords}[2][0]{\foreach \tmp in #2{
    \foreach \testVal[count=\i] in \tmp{
        (\pgfval{\i+#1},\testVal)
    }
}%foreach
}%newcommand

Test is \test

\newcommand{\tester}{\makeCoords{\test}}
% \newcommand{\tester}{ { (1.0,3)  (2.0,4)  (3.0,2)  (4.0,5) } }

tester is \tester  % Print out for debugging

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={timestep},
        ylabel={Location(x)},
        xmin=0, xmax=6,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style = dashed
    ]    
    
    \addplot coordinates { {\tester} };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the pgf foreach isn't expandable, and makes each item a local group, so you have something like `\addplot coordinates { \bgroup \def\tmp{1,2}(\tmp)\egroup \bgroup \def\tmp{3,4}(\tmp)\egroup  };` which prints as `(1,2)(3,4)` but wouldn't work for similar reasons

Comment: I don't know if you want to anything else, but would something like this work for you: https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/8a7f2bcd725dbd58b930ea220e033b47

Comment: Thank you @TorbjørnT. that works to generate the graph.  The problem is I am generating other graphs from the same numbers.  For example, I may want the 2nd element in test to be the mean of a Gaussian distribution that will be graphed elsewhere in the code.  So, while that code snippet fixes my code as it, it doesn't help my bigger problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is there a way to combine groups or make this kind of thing work?  Very helpful to know why it is not working currently.  Thanks!

Comment: It's possible to extract specific cells from a table with `\pgfplotstablegetelem` so you might be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. !  If you want to create an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that using a `pgfplotstable` table would work. It's certainly straightforward to plot columns from such a table, and use `x expr` to calculate a x-value for the plot. See example below.

Individual values from the table can be accessed with `\pgfplotstablegetelem{<row>}{<column>}\of\tablename`, which saves the result in `\pgfplotsretval`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
3
4
2
5
}\test

You can print the table:

% the option hides the header row
\pgfplotstabletypeset[every head row/.style={output empty row}]\test


% indexing in tables starts at zero, so this is the third row, first column
\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{[index]0}\of\test
\pgfmathsetmacro\foo{\pgfplotsretval}

Now the third element in the table is \foo.

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={timestep},
        ylabel={Location(x)},
        xmin=0, xmax=6,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style = dashed
    ]    
    
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y index=0] {\test};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise, here is an solution with [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{functional}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\test}{3,4,2,5}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \MakeCoords {M} {
  \ClistClear \lTmpaClist
  \IntZero \lTmpaInt
  \ClistVarMapInline #1 {
    \IntIncr \lTmpaInt
    \ClistPutRight \lTmpaClist {\Expand{{(\OnlyValue\lTmpaInt,##1)}}}
  }
  \TlSet #1 {\ClistVarJoin \lTmpaClist {~}}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

Test is \test

\MakeCoords \test

Test is \test

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={timestep},
    ylabel={Location(x)},
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style = dashed
  ]    
  \addplot coordinates { {\test} };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `\foreach`-loop for collecting things within a scratch macro.
When the loop is done use the scratch-macro for performing whatsoever action with the scratch-macro's expansion.
Action could, e.g., be a command for defining a macro `\tester` holding coordinates.

```
\DefineCoordsMacro[⟨x-shift of coordinates⟩]%
                  {⟨definition-command for defining macro holding list of coordinates⟩}%
                  {⟨braced comma-list or macro holding unbraced comma-list of y-values of coordinates⟩}
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand\Scratchmacro{}
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DefineCoordsMacro}[3][0]{%
  \begingroup
  \gdef\Scratchmacro{ }%
  \foreach \testVal[count=\i] in #3{%
    \pgfmathparse{\i+#1}%
    \xdef\Scratchmacro{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\Scratchmacro}%
      (%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
      ,%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\testVal}%
      ) %
    }%
  }%foreach
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\Scratchmacro}}{\endgroup#2}%
}%newcommand
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\test}{3,4,2,5}
\DefineCoordsMacro{\newcommand\tester}{\test}
%\DefineCoordsMacro[2]{\renewcommand\tester}{{3,4,2,5}}

% Print out for debugging:
\noindent
The meaning of the macro \texttt{\string\test} is:\\ \texttt{\meaning\test}

\noindent
The meaning of the macro \texttt{\string\tester} is:\\ \texttt{\meaning\tester}

\begin{figure}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={timestep},
        ylabel={Location(x)},
        xmin=0, xmax=6,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style = dashed
    ]    
    
    \addplot coordinates { {\tester} };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]